# Get Secret from Azure Key Vault using Perl

Tags: perl, azure-keyvault

I have explored all related documentation provided by Microsoft and other related blogs to Azure key vault but have been unable to find how to get a Secret from Azure Key Vault using Perl scripting.

Does Microsoft support reading Secret value from Azure Key Vault using Perl?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/client-libraries : only these are supported by Microsoft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a REST client such as [REST::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) and call the [Get Secret endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/get-secret/get-secret).

For Azure AD authentication you will need to use an Oauth2 library such as [Net::OAuth2::AuthorizationServer.](https://github.com/Humanstate/net-oauth2-authorizationserver)

For more information take a look to [Authentication in Azure Key Vault.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication)